# Load classifier on Heroku Python

Tags: python, opencv, heroku, cascade-classifier

I am loading a cascade classifier from a file in OpenCV using python. Since the `CascadeClassifier()` method requires the filename to be the absolute filename, I have to load the absolute filename.

However, I am deploying and using it on Heroku and I can't seem to get the absolute path of the file. I've tried using `os.getcwd() + '\cascader_file.xml'`, but that still does not work.

I would like to know how to load the classifier on the Heroku deployment

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. All I needed to do was use the `os.path.abspath()` method to convert the relative path to an absolute path

Answer (score 0):

if the file you are looking for is by the side of your script, you can get the directory of the script and then locate the target resource/conf file. That's better practice than using `os.getcwd` since your current directory maybe not the same directory of your script.

for example, your directory is like this:

```
-- my_project
  |-- main.py
  |-- cascader_file.xml
```

to locate `cascader_file.xml` in script `main.py`:

```
d = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))  # your script's dir, my_project
filepath = os.path.join(d, "cascader_file.xml")
filepath = os.path.abspath(filepath) # make it an absolute path
```

btw, using `os.path.join` is more secure and more platform compatible than directly concat path parts.